# Repeat view entry for each value of multivalue field

Tags: 7, views, entities, commerce

I am using commerce module in D7. Each order can have a single line item, but you can have whatever quantity you like in that line item. For each item of this quantity I store a text value that is held in a multivalue text field on the list-item itself.

So you have:

> Product 1  Quantity 1 Price $10  Information: Item1Text
>
> Product 2          Quantity 3     Price $10 Information: Item1Text, Item2Text, Item3Text

I would like to have a view for each order to display each item of the line item as a separate entry. So for example:

> Product 2           Price $10           Information: Item1Text
>
> Product 2           Price $10           Information: Item2Text
>
> Product 2           Price $10           Information: Item3Text

Is this at all possible, because I have tried all the tricks that I know, but cannot produce such a view.
The reason I need something like this is that I can have a separate invoice for each of the items included in the order, besides them being purchased together. So if you buy 3 balls, I would create 3 invoices each describing the purchase of a single ball.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all the rest of the invoice info should be repeated as well, and not just the line items.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured out how to do this.

I order for the line item to repeat itself I unchecked the single line representation for multivalue field.

And in order to repeat the whole invoice I call a view from within another view.